# Inputing array of strings inside a function

Tags: c

I am trying to input to this array of strings with myFgets, but it is telling me that I have an access violation error when I do so.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void myFgets(char str[], int size)
{
    fgets(str, size, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}
void enterFriends(char** friendsArr)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("enter friend %d: ", i + 1);
        
        myFgets(friendsArr[i], 10);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char friendsArr[3][10] = { ' ' };
    int i = 0;

    enterFriends(friendsArr);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        puts(friendsArr[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the exact input that caused the access violation?

Comment: `friendsArr[3][10]` does not decay to "a pointer to a pointer". I suggest the function should be `void enterFriends(char friendsArr[][10])`

Comment: `friendsArr` is type `char (*)[10]` which is not the same as `char **`. (the first is a *pointer-to-array*, the second is a *pointer-to-pointer*) Since type controls pointer arithmetic (e.g. the offset between `p` and `p + 1`), that is where your access violation arises. An equivalent form is `void enterFriends(char (*friendsArr)[10])`

Comment: any input gives me this error:
Access violation writing location

Comment: Side note: your tiny string array can only be length 9 each but you waste 1  char by using it for a newline, even though you later truncate the string. So the maximum name length is only 8, which some of my friends would break.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment, your access violation is because `friendsArr` is type `char (*)[10]` which is not the same as `char **`. (the first is a *pointer-to-array*, the second is a *pointer-to-pointer*) **Type controls pointer arithmetic.** (e.g. the offset between `p` and `p + 1`). Your 3 x 10 2D array is an *array of 1D arrays*.

Since an array is converted to a pointer to its first element<sup>1</sup>, `friendsArr` is converted to a pointer to the first *array* (e.g. a 10-character array), which is why the formal type on access is `char (*)[10]` (a pointer to array of 10-characters). So when you access the next pointer, the offset is to the beginning of the next 1D array (offset of 10-characters/bytes).

When you attempt to pass the array as `char **`, the offset is no longer 10-character, but instead `sizeof (a_pointer)`. So the offset will be either 4-bytes on x86 of 8-bytes on x86_64. So what happens is you read the first string into the first 1D array, advance 8-bytes (or 4-bytes) and then attempt to read the next string into the same 1D array beginning at the 8<sup>th</sup> (or 4<sup>th</sup>) element of the array corrupting the input.

Which brings up the next critical point you are missing. You must ALWAYS check the return of every input function used to determine whether the input succeeded or failed. It is 100% valid for the user to press <kbd>ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl + z</kbd> on windows) to generate a manual `EOF` to cancel input. By checking the return of `fgets()` you can properly handle that case. Further, any function you write that takes input must have a meaningful return type that can communicate success or failure of the input back to the caller.

In `myFgets()`, returning a pointer to the string on success (or `NULL` on failure) would tell `enterFriends()` if that input succeeded or failed. Since `enterFriends()` also relies on that return, it too needs a meaningful return type to communicate how many inputs succeeded. Which brings up an additional point, you cannot simply loop a fixed number of times in `enterFriends()`, but instead need to condition your loop on a successful read of the number of friends less than your maximum. If the user cancels input, you still want to be able to return the number that were successfully entered.

(**note:** you can adjust the test to require that all inputs are made, re-prompting for the canceled input -- up to you)

Don't use *MagicNumbers* in your code (e.g. `3`, `10`), instead:

```
#define NFRIENDS      3     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC       1024
```

(**note:** Rule: *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size*, `10` is way to short for user input. Unless you are on an embedded system with limited physical memory, then a 256-byte to 2048-byte buffer is fine. For example, GCC defines `BUFSIZ` as `8192`, VS defines it as `512`)

This also plays into whether your code is mixing VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) as parameters with your declarations of Plain-Old arrays in `main()`. While the difference is largely semantics in this case, be aware that compiler support for VLAs is optional beginning with C11.

So putting that altogether, you can rewrite your code slightly, tweaking the function parameters and returns to avoid VLAs and provided minimal necessary returns to communicate the success or failure of input and how many friends were read as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NFRIENDS      3     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC       1024

/* every function that takes input must provide a meaningful return
 * that can indicate success or failure to the caller.
 * returns pointer to string on success, NULL otherwise.
 */
char *myFgets (char *str, int size)
{
    if (!fgets (str, size, stdin)) {        /* validate EVERY input */
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return NULL;
    }
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;            /* good job using strcspn() */

    return str;
}

/* do not use MagicNumbers, pass a parameter for number of friends */
int enterFriends (char (*friendsArr)[MAXC], size_t size, int nfriends)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < nfriends) {                  /* can't use a fixed number */
        printf ("enter friend %d: ", i + 1);
        
        if (!myFgets (friendsArr[i], size)) /* if user cancels, break loop */
            break;
        
        i += 1;                         /* only increment after good read */
    }

    return i;       /* return number of friends read */
}

int main(void)
{
    char friendsArr[NFRIENDS][MAXC] = {""}; /* initialize all elements zero */
    int i = 0,
        friends = 0;

    friends = enterFriends (friendsArr, MAXC, NFRIENDS);

    for (i = 0; i < friends; i++) {
        puts (friendsArr[i]);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/friendsarray 
enter friend 1: Mickey Mouse
enter friend 2: Minnie Mouse
enter friend 3: Goofy (the dog)
Mickey Mouse
Minnie Mouse
Goofy (the dog)
```

or intentionally canceling the last input:

```
$ ./bin/friendsarray 
enter friend 1: Mickey Mouse
enter friend 2: Minnie Mouse
enter friend 3: (user canceled input)
Mickey Mouse
Minnie Mouse
```

which properly preserves the two good inputs before the cancellation occurred.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Footnotes:**

**1.** [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are passing a 2D array in a function is not correct.

Simply pass in the array size along with it.

Eg:

```c
void enterFriends(int m,int n,char friendsArr[m][n]){

}

// while calling that function
enterFriends(3,10,friendsArr);
```

Reference link: https://www.techiedelight.com/pass-2d-array-function-parameter/

Full Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void myFgets(char str[], int size)
{
    fgets(str, size, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}
void enterFriends(int m,int n,char friendsArr[m][n])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("enter friend %d: ", i + 1);
        
        myFgets(friendsArr[i], 10);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char friendsArr[3][10] = { ' ' };
    int i = 0;

    enterFriends(3,10,friendsArr);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        puts(friendsArr[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void myFgets(char str[], int size)
{
    fgets(str, size, stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
}
void enterFriends(size_t size, char (*friendsArr)[size])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("enter friend %d: ", i + 1);
        
        myFgets(friendsArr[i], 10);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char friendsArr[3][10] = { ' ' };
    int i = 0;

    enterFriends(10, friendsArr);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        puts(friendsArr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if your answer explained what was wrong, instead of providing a code-only answer (even if the comments already provided this explanation).

Comment: Nit, be aware `void enterFriends(size_t size, char (*friendsArr)[size])` creates a pointer to a VLA unless `size` is a defined constant.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin we want pointer to array. It does not matter if it is VLA or not. It only needed for the correct pointer arithmetics.

Comment: No dings, that is why I said the comment was a "Nit", but beginning with C11, VLA support by compilers is optional (though most will continue to support it). May want to comment on the use of *MagicNumbers* and need to **check the return** of every input function (and provide a meaningful return type for any function taking input so success or failure can be indicated to the caller.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Magic numbers and return values are not in the scope of this question.